# How do I force a rollover at application startup with Log4net RolloverFileAppender?

Tags: log4net

Have Log4Net configured in our application to use a date stamped name and a 10Meg file size limit.
This automatically causes a rollover to a new file at midnight and whenever the 10Meg limit is reached.
I would also like to roll over the logging to a new file each time the application is started (or closed).
Can I get all three roll over behaviours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set [appendToFile](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.AppendToFile.html) to false in your config file.

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
....
  <appendToFile value="false" />
....
</appender>
```

EDIT: To answer Craig's comment:

If you properly setup StaticLogFileName and CountDirection (see http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.html for more), then things roll as desired. We programmatically configure the logger in our app where we use this, but this is what the code looks like:

```
Dim Layout As New PatternLayout("%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff} [%-6thread] %-5level %type{2}.%method(%line) - %message%newline") 
Dim Appender As New log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender()
Appender.File = Path.Combine(FileSystemHelper.LogDirectory, LogFileName)
Appender.Layout = Layout
Appender.AppendToFile = False ' we will start a new one when the program starts'
Appender.Name = "RollingLogFileAppender"
Appender.Threshold = LogLevel() 'May want to set this by configuration'
Appender.RollingStyle = log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size 'This means it will start a new log file each time the log grows to 10Mb'
Appender.MaximumFileSize = "10MB"
Appender.MaxSizeRollBackups = -1 'keep an infinite number of logs'
Appender.StaticLogFileName = True
Appender.CountDirection = 1 ' to reduce rollover costs'
log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(Appender)
Appender.ActivateOptions()
```

Comment: Note that this *replaces* the preexisting file. Whether or not you consider this a "rollover" is a matter of interpretation. (For me, rollover implies leaving the older log around.)

Comment: @Bob King - any idea what the right settings for CountDirection and StaticLogFileName are to get it to roll (ie copy old log somewhere else) on application start? I've set RollingStyle=Once,  CountDirection=1, StaticLogFileName=true, AppendToFile=false but I cannot get it to roll as desired. I've also experimented with a variety of other settings without luck

Comment: @fostandy - try setting rolling style to something other than once. Size works for us. Sorry, just noticed that comment is over a year old :-(