# C# - log4net rollover on date, size, and application relaunch

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I'm working on a wpf application that uses log4net. It currently logs to a single file and only rolls over when it grows too large. I am trying to modify this so that it grows over when the file grows too large, when the date changes, or when the application is relaunched.

I am trying to get output as close to the following as possible

```
App_2017-07-06.0.txt    //First launch on 2017-07-06
App_2017-07-06.1.txt    //Rollover due to size limit
App_2017-07-06.2.txt    //Application relaunch
App_2017-07-06.3.txt    //Rollover due to size limit
App_2017-07-07.0.txt    //Rollover due to date change
App_2017-07-07.1.txt    //Rollover due to size limit
App_2017-07-07.2.txt    //Application relaunch - Currently Logging File
```

From what I understand from the documentation, The rolling style can be set to "compostite" to capture date and size or it can be set to "once" to capture application relaunches. It doesn't seem to have a way to do all 3: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_RollingFileAppender_RollingMode.htm

I got it to the point where everything looks correct and works except the application relaunch overwrites a pre existing file (I imagine because of the appendToFile property). I just cant seem to get it working the way I need to and I can't find any answers in the documentation.

This question seems to be trying to achieve a similar goal, but did not solve my problem: 
[How do I force a rollover at application startup with Log4net RolloverFileAppender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222210/how-do-i-force-a-rollover-at-application-startup-with-log4net-rolloverfileappend)

Am I missing something? Is it just not possible to do this with log4net?

My current configuration

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Log\App.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="false" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10KB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
      <countDirection value="1" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level User = %username  Class = %property{ClassName}  Method = %property{MethodName}%newlineMessage - %message%newline%exception%newline***************************************" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

My current output

```
App_2017-07-06.0.txt    //First launch on 2017-07-06
App_2017-07-06.1.txt    //Rollover due to size limit
App_2017-07-06.1.txt    //Application relaunch - overwrites pre-existing file
App_2017-07-06.2.txt    //Rollover due to size limit
App_2017-07-07.0.txt    //Rollover due to date change
App_2017-07-07.1.txt    //Rollover due to size limit
App_2017-07-07.1.txt    //Application relaunch - overwrites pre-existing file - Currently logging file
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know log4net copies the log file to xxxx.{number}.txt when it rolls over to the next file. So your first App_2017-07-06.1.txt was never created and is still called App_2017-07-06.txt when the application restarts. You have  configured so App_2017-07-06.txt will be overridden and your first App_2017-07-06.1.txt was never created.

You can configure `<appendToFile value="true" />` to not override the existing file.